# capture output of install.packages

Tags: r, cran

I would like to capture the complete output of the install.packages command in a variable. However, the messages that are printed during the installation are a result of calling system() with intern=FALSE. As a result they are not really messages/warnings/print. Is there any way to capture this information into a variable? E.g.

```
> sink(tempfile())
> bla <- suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(capture.output(system('whoami'))));
jeroen
```

Or:

```
> sink(tempfile())
> bla <- suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(capture.output(install.packages("XML"))));
```

Still prints everything to screen...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can launch a separate R process:

```
system( "Rscript -e 'install.packages(\"XML\")'", intern=TRUE )
```

Comment: But be careful because that's not guaranteed to run the same R that you're currently running, and libpaths etc may/will be different

Comment: Not optimal, but it will do for my purpose. I suppose there is no other way.